# Higher dimension leads to different optimization?

Tags: optimization, parametric, dimension-theory-analysis

It appears z= f(x,y) has a global max/min at another particular (x,y). Using only one

independent variable $x$ at fixed $y$ i.e., for z = f(x) I get another max/min point

for $x$ optimum point location.

Max[f(x)] in 2D-space is way different compared to  max[f(x,y)] in 3D-space.

I am searching for some article or textbook supporting this intuition.

Could you recommend any relevant literature for me so I can go from normal derivatives

to using partial derivatives in finding extrema? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your notation is weird. Do you mean with $f(x,0)$ vs $f(x,y)$ (with $x$ in $R^2$ and $y$ in $R$)

Comment: Question has been revised now. You will not find any specific books on this, as it is very basic. If you fix some decision variable, you can only get worse.